# Saving data in Swift/iOS apps

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to fix my code to save data and so that the meals entered by the user are saved for when they close the app and reopen it. I added a print statement in the addMeal function to debug, and it works on the first time opening the app, but when the app is closed and reopened, the print statement is not reached (even though the meals are still getting added, because when I use the meals to generate a meal plan, the meals added after reopening show up on the meal plan???).

I have tried using UserDefaults to save the meals entered by the user and loading them when the app is closed and reopened. The meals are used to generate a meal plan. Any meals entered by the user and added should be remembered by the app for all future uses.

```
    var meals: [String] = []
    var mealIngredients: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if let stateDictionary = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "savedState") {
            // Restore any properties you want to restore
            meals = stateDictionary["meals"] as? [String] ?? []
            mealIngredients = stateDictionary["mealIngredients"] as? [String] ?? []
        }
    }

    @IBAction func addMeal(_ sender: Any) {
        if let mealName = mealNameField.text, let mealIngredients = mealIngredientsField.text {
            if mealName != "" && mealIngredients != "" {
                meals.append(mealName)
                print("Added")
                self.mealIngredients.append(mealIngredients)
                mealNameField.text = ""
                mealIngredientsField.text = ""
                
                UserDefaults.standard.set(meals, forKey: "meals")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(mealIngredients, forKey: "mealIngredients")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nowhere I see where you write `forKey:savedState"`, so you don't pass the `if let stateDictionary =`? And even if it's the case, then it should be ` meals = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "meals") as? [String] ?? []` and same lgic for ingredients

Answer (score 0):

You **load** a **dictionary** but you **save** two **arrays**. So loading the data always fails reliably.

Put the two arrays into a dictionary and save this

```
   @IBAction func addMeal(_ sender: Any) {
        if let mealName = mealNameField.text, !mealName.isEmpty,
           let mealIngredients = mealIngredientsField.text, !mealIngredients.isEmpty {
            
            meals.append(mealName)
            print("Added")
            self.mealIngredients.append(mealIngredients)
            mealNameField.text = ""
            mealIngredientsField.text = ""
            let stateDictionary = ["meals":meals, "mealIngredients":mealIngredients]  
            UserDefaults.standard.set(stateDictionary, forKey: "savedState")
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've fixed this, but I realized that another problem could be that viewDidLoad() is not being called when I close the app and reopen it. I added a print statement after super.viewDidLoad(), and it is only printing after the initial launch of the app, not after the app is closed and reopened.

Comment: Then load the data in `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: I loaded the data in viewWillAppear, and added a print statement inside of viewWillAppear, but that print statement is still not being reached after closing the app and reopening it. It is only printed when the app is launched for the first time.

Comment: This is beyond the scope of this question, but at least `viewWillAppear` is supposed to be called. Did you use the proper syntax?

Comment: Yes, I did.     override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get value for key `UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "savedState")`.

But you're only writing two arrays:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(meals, forKey: "meals")
UserDefaults.standard.set(mealIngredients, forKey: "mealIngredients")
```

There's no value for key `savedState`

Also, you can use `mealName.isEmpty()` instead of `mealName == ""`